# Dataframe to List of List conversion based on the name of column in Python

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

Input:

Dataframe

```
col1    col2
item1   10
item1   20
item1   25
item2   56
item2   36
item3   1
```

Output:

List of List

```
[[10,20,25],[56,36],[1]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create `Series` of `lists` by `groupby` with [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) and last convert it to `list`:

```
L = df.groupby('col1')['col2'].apply(list).tolist()
print (L)
[[10, 20, 25], [56, 36], [1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can [`GroupBy`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) `col1` and extract lists from each group of on `col2`:

```
df.groupby('col1').col2.apply(list).values.tolist()
# [[10, 20, 25], [56, 36], [1]]
```